# Does a JS execution context persist in memory after it completes (if a reference to a lexical environment created in it remains)?

Tags: javascript

Or is the execution context object garbage collected, leaving only the lexical environment objects still referenced (i.e. referenced by a closure)?

[image]

i.e do the Execution context objects on the left get garbage collected when they're popped off the stack, while [[Environment]] remains if referenced by a closure?

Also wondering:

Does the ExecutionContext a) create the global/window/module-type object and b) set its 'this' property's value to point to it. (with global and window being properties of the ExecutionContext).

or does ExecutionContext == global & window-type objects?

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you're looking for if you would describe some practical real-world effect of things working (or not working) the way you're asking.

Comment: Do you think my image addition helps? 

This is more of a theory/under the hood, hidden JS engine object question. Not sure how I'd show the effect of 'things working or not working' here.

Answer (score 2):

A variable will stay in memory until there is at least one identifier linked to it. If you have some variables in closure they will stay in memory until this closure is alive.

```js
function foo() {
  const a = 1;
  const b = 2;
  
  return function boo() {
    return a + b;
  }
}

const moo = foo() //moo is now linked to the boo closure
```

In the example all the links are coming this way:

1. **moo** is linked to the **boo**
2. **boo** is linked to its own Lexical Environment object
3. boo's Lexical Environment contains Scope (link to the outer foo's Lexical Environment)
4. as the variables **a** and **b** are used in **boo**, they are also stored in memory. foo's Lexical Environment contains links to **a** and **b**

So, as long as there are **moo**, variables **a** and **b** will be stored in memory. In this case, we can set moo to **null**. After this, there is no way Garbage Collector would reach a and b from the root. That means that variables will be removed automatically.